# jQuery plugin: add eventlistener to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, event-listener

I'm creating a small jQuery plugin for personal use which adds some content to the document when you hover over an element.

Currently this is the (simplified) code:

```
    (function($){
    $.fn.tempFnName = function(options){

        var element = $('<div />');

        return this
        .each(function(){
            $(this)
            .on('mouseenter',
                function(){
                    $('body')
                    .append(element);
                })
            .on('mouseleave',
                function(){
                    element.remove();
                });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

For some reason this doesn't work. Looking around on google and stackoverflow didn't provide an answer. What am I doing wrong?

**edit:** As pointed out by WTK, there's nothing wrong with this code. The following code shows how the plugin should be implemented.

```
function appendAddAnchor(){
    return $('<a />').tempFnName();
}

//even if I try the following, the click event will not work!
function appendAddAnchor(){
    return $('<a />')
            .click(function(){console.log('test')});
            .tempFnName();
}
```

This is really strange to me, because I used to have Bootstrap' `.tooltip()` chained to the same `$('<a />')` and this worked without any issues...

Comment: Works for me http://jsbin.com/unelox/1/edit

Comment: Probably something important got removed during the "simplification" of your code.

Comment: I suggest trying to find a simplification that reproduces your problem on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3):

I tried this in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gm4jk/2/

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.tempFnName = function(options){
        var element = $('<div/>');
        element.html('aTest');
        return this.each( function(){
            $(this).mouseenter(function(){
                $('body').append(element);
            });
            $(this).mouseleave(function(){
                element.remove();
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#start').tempFnName();
```

and it is working just fine. It may be that you are running into compatibility issues.

from the jQuery documentation:

"The mouseenter JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer. Because of the event's general utility, jQuery simulates this event so that it can be used regardless of browser. This event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer enters the element. Any HTML element can receive this event."

I read that to mean if you are not using the shorthand bind method, you may not be getting the 'emulated' event instead jQuery may be looking for the actual event which, in all but IE, does not exist.

To be clear, I also got it to work with your code in jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/zFKXx/2/